# Component-based application with scalability in mind: OSGi or Akka?

Tags: osgi, akka

For my master thesis I'm developing an application framework for selling tickets for large events. My main requirements are modifiability, scalability and performance. My clients (event organisers) should be able to easily replace a component at runtime and add functionality. An example of such a component could be the seat assignment component.

My mentors said to look at OSGi. The idea of loosely coupled bundles is certainly appealing. When looking for alternatives I discovered Akka. This framework promises a lot of things, like scalability and high performance. I wondered if Akka's concept of actors suits my modifiability requirements. Akka seems more productive than OSGi, so development would be faster. Akka also seems more fit for scalability. With OSGi I would have a harder time.

If you have experience in both OSGi and Akka, which would you recommend for me? What are the pro and cons of both technologies when comparing them? And finally, are there are any good alternatives to OSGi or Akka that cover my requirements?

**EDIT**

First, thank you for the replies so far, you're a great help.
As mentioned below, I'm trying to compare apples and pears. A more logical question would be: How can OSGi and Akka be used together and benefit from each other? How is this structured? Do all your actors reside in one OSGi bundle, do they each get a separate bundle, is there a hybrid solution or isn't there really a 'right' way to do it?

**EDIT bis**

I posted a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163507/how-can-osgi-and-akka-benefit-from-each-other-how-is-this-structured), asking how to combine OSGi and Akka.

Comment: I think you should open a new question for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Peter says they are not directly comparable. In fact you can use them together and they should be quite complementary.

Akka provides an asynchronous communications API. OSGi provides a modular, service-oriented framework. There is nothing in Akka, for example, that would solve the problem of isolating modules so that they cannot have visibility of each others' internals. Likewise there is nothing in OSGi quite like the async communications provided by Akka. So use them together and you get the best of both worlds...

OSGi does have synchronous Services, which are the principal method of communication between modules in a single JVM. OSGi also has a Remote Services layer that can be used for communication between remote machines. This is probably the area where OSGi and Akka most directly overlap, I suppose. But even here I think there is potential for cooperation. For example, OSGi Remote Services has a really powerful discovery mechanism that allows us to advertise capabilities on the network. You could possibly use this discovery to find Akka actors that are available for you to communicate with.

I'm not aware of anybody actually working on this as present, so I think that exploring and expanding on this idea would be an excellent topic for a master's thesis!

Which university do you attend? The OSGi Alliance is very interested in fostering links with the academic community, perhaps we could set up an online meeting with you and your professor?

Comment: As axiopisty mentioned, I should use OSGi for my modifiability and hot swapping requirements and Akka for my scalability and performance issues? I'm not sure how to structure OSGi and Akka together.

I'm at Ghent University. I'm currently working on my SOTA. My mentors just said to look into OSGi. Since I'm unexperienced with technologies like OSGi and Akka I was a bit confused, resulting in a somewhat illogical question.

I'm afraid a meeting wouldn't be possible, my mentors and professor have a tight schedule. Thank you anyways for proposing, it's kind of you.

Comment: Well it seems not many people are experienced with both Akka and OSGi... which is what makes this a good research project! I suggest learning each technology individually through its tutorials etc; then you will have a better idea of how to bring them together.

Answer (score 2):

I think you compare apple and pears. You can run Scala code on OSGi (though their binary compatibility is horrible).

Scala is a programming language, and Akka a messaging library. OSGi is a dynamic component system. So not sure how you can compare them

Comment: I'm not sure why you're referring to Scala here. With scalability I mean an application that can scale from one node to for example 10 nodes with ease.

As for the comparison between OSGi and Akka. I know they're difficult to compare, that's why I couldn't find a lot when googling, but I must make a decision which to use here. When using OSGi, I would probably not use pure OSGi, but something like Aries or Spring. Which, including Akka, would you recommend?

Comment: Apparently Akka is sometimes used in an OSGi environment. How is Akka used in this manner? Bundles are then composed of different actors?

Comment: I've no hands on experience with Akka ... I think you have to read up on both technologies to see what parts of each you want to use. My advice: keep it simple when you start. Both Aries and Spring are huge frameworks while the problem seems quite straightforward.

Comment: Akka has an implementation in both Java and Scala. I think the Scala version is more widely used. This might be why Scala was brought up. But using the Akka framework does not necessarily imply that the application utilizing the framework is written in Scala. It might be the case though that the framework itself is, I'm not sure.

@Peter - Can you point me to an explanation of the horrible binary compatibility between OSGi and Scala? I'm just curious because I thought all Scala code compiles to Java byte code. If so, why would there be any binary compatibility issues?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with both Neil and Peter, you're asking us to make a comparison between apples and oranges. You can use both frameworks together. I'm currently working on a project with the same main requirements you specified. I'm creating a prototype that demonstrates using both technologies together, OSGi to provide modularity and updatability, and Akka to provide scalability and performance.

[If you would like to see both frameworks working together you can play with the sample application I posted on github](https://github.com/axiopisty/scala-actors-javafx-osgi-demo).

Comment: So, if I understand your project structure correctly, you develop only one OSGi bundle with all your actors in it? Can this also be divided in several bundles, and what are the pro/cons and use cases of that?

Comment: I should clarify that this demo is my first attempt with both OSGi and the Akka framework. So my experience with them is limited and there is probably a better way of doing things than what I've done.

I want to use OSGi to provide updatability and extensibility, and use Actors to simplify both the logic of the application and the management of threads/concurrency. Akka also allows simple integration with remote applications/services.

I would not say that the project structure of the application implies 1 bundle with all the actors in it. Actually it would be quite the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't an apples to apples comparison. They are Orthogonal to each other and, if anything, complement each other. Use both.